# Applying GAM on a timeseries dataset

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to create a gam model on a time series data. In `mydata`, I have just two columns: `Var1` and `date`(which is from Jan 2013 to Dec 2018). 
This is the code that I am using:

```
training.samples <- mydata$Var1 %>% createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
    train.data  <- mydata[training.samples, ]
    test.data <- mydata[-training.samples, ]

    library(mgcv)
    # Build the model
    model <- gam(Var1 ~ s(date, bs="cr"), data = train.data, fit= TRUE)



Error in names(dat) <- object$term : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

My question is: Is there something wrong in this code or is there some fundamental difference for using a date variable in the gam function? Any help woule be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the output of `str(train.data)` to the question.

Comment: If your variable train.data$date is of class "Date" and you feed it this way into the model it gives an error. You might want to transforme Date into some numerical format first (for example by using as.numeric(), but be careful that the numerical values still represent the date-values on the scale as you want it to be)

Comment: Hey, thanks! "as.numeric()" is working with my data.